# Don't stay up late when you study your lessons or study?

Tags: vocabulary

Don't stay up late when you study your lessons.
In this sentence, is the use of the phrase "study your lessons" natural? If it is not natural, should I write like the following?Don't stay up late when you study. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both are correct, but *study your lesson* says specifically what to study.

Answer (score 4):

"... when you study" is fine and is commonly used when describing something a student might do (or should do!).

"... when you study your lessons" is grammatically correct and sensible, but not something a fluent speaker is likely to say. We generally only put something after "study" if it's not obvious. We specify if we are talking about studying a specific subject. "... when you are studying geography". If the person is not a student, we often specify what he is studying. I mean, if someone is working a full time job and taking just one class on the side, etc. This is especially true if it is not a "normal" school. Like, "Bob is studying French on the Internet in his spare time."